# How to display child component custom display elements in parent component html table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a html table where I am showing all of my data from a previous saved state. I have the main component called Options-Grid, where there can be multiple options for each label (options = columns, labels = rows). The labels are statically defined, but the data in each subsequent option varies by option.

I have a component that I want to display in the grid with custom html elements, but when I use the selector tag for that component inside of the table, the display from the component is all forced into one cell. I want the content from the inserted component to match the display of the parent component (options-grid).

Here's options grid that is home to the main table:

```
<table>
    <tbody *ngFor="let section of template?.type[1].option[0].sections; let i = index">
            <tr *ngFor="let label of section.labels"
                id="row-tag">
                <td *ngIf="(label.label != 'Expense')">
                    {{label.label}}
                </td>
                <td *ngFor="let option of this.service.c.options; let x = index">
                    <div *ngIf="i == 0">
                        <f [label]="label.label"
                                [code]="label.code"
                                [num]="x">
                        </f>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="i == 1">
                        <f [label]="label.label"
                                [description]="label.description"
                                [num]="x"
                                [type]="label.type">
                        </f>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
            **<i-f [label]="label"></i-f>**
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the i-f component with a subset of the table data

```
<tr id="row-tag">
    <td>
        {{label}}
    </td>
    <td *ngFor="let option of this.service.c.options">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div *ngIf="fModel">
                {{ range }}
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="number"/>
                <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
            <app-ex (exSaveButtonClick)="toggleAndBindEx($event)"
                    [modExModalValues]="modExModalValues">
            </app-ex>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td *ngFor="let option of this.service.c.options">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div *ngIf="fModel">
                {{ exRange }}
            </div>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <input type="number"/>
                <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I would just move the i-f component outside of the options-grid table. Then you can just match the formatting to the options-grid table to make it look like a part of the same table.